# How to check for path expansion for executables

Tags: bash

Like most makefiles, I have some bash scripts that use variables for executables.  For example, `$mysql_exec` for /usr/bin/mysql.  I would like to be able to say something like:

`mysql_exec=mysql`

to use $PATH or

`mysql_exec=/usr/bin/mysql`

to get an absolute location without $PATH.  I also want to check to see if the executable is valid using something like this:

`if [ ! -x $mysql_exec ] ...`

However, this command:

`if [ ! -x "mysql" ]; then print "oh oh"; fi`

Actually prints "oh oh", even though mysql is in my $PATH.  From the command-line, typing `mysql` has the same effect as typing `/usr/bin/mysql`.  So, how do I get bash *really* check to see if $mysql_exec is an executable ($PATH and all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, you can use the built-in `type -P` to force a resolution against the `PATH` or `type -p` to show the path only if there's no alias or function by that name. Using `type` avoids calling an external such as `which`.

Something like this may do what you're looking for:

```
[ -x "$(type -p "$mysql_exec")" ]
```

whether you use

```
mysql_exec=mysql
```

or

```
mysql_exec=/usr/bin/mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

`which` is a small program that checks `$PATH` for a program specified as an argument:

```
$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
```

Another useful utility (that isn't installed on all systems but is included in GNU CoreUtils) is `readlink`. `readlink` can give you back a full and absolute path, without symlinks. For example:

```
$ cd ~me/bin
$ ln -s `which mysql` mysupersql
$ readlink -f mysupersql
/usr/bin/mysql
```

I often use a combination of both so I know that the path is both absolute and not a symlink:

```
mysql_exec=$(readlink -f `which mysql`)
if [ ! -x "$mysql_exec" ] ; then
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kaleb's answer, you an also check if the file is a symlink using `if [-L $file]` and follow that symlink if you can't install readlink. The rest of the check though remains as the way Kaleb mentioned.